# How to join multiple tables in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join

Hi friends I have 3 table topups, withdraws and transfers these 3 tables belongs to the user table. I have to find all the records which belongs to the users. I tried with inner join as follows:-

```
SELECT * FROM users u
INNER JOIN topups t
  ON u.id = t.user_id
INNER JOIN withdraws w
  ON u.id = w.user_id
INNER JOIN transfers tf
  ON u.id = tf.user_id
```

But this query returns only the common records between the 3 tables. i have to find all those records which belongs to the user for each table.

Suppose i have 2 records in topups which belongs to user id 1, 3 records in withdraws which belongs to user id 2 and 5 records in transfers which belongs to user id 3 so i should get the total 10 records.

sample data:-

**topups**

```
+--------+---------+---------+
| amount | result  | user_id |
+--------+---------+---------+
|     10 | success |       1 |
|     20 | failed  |       2 |
+--------+---------+---------+
```

**withdraws**

```
+---------+----------+
|w_amount |  user_id |
+---------+----------+
|     10  |        1 |
|     20  |        2 |
|     30  |       10 |
+---------+----------+
```

**Transfers**

```
+--------+--------+---------+
| method | amount | user_id |
+--------+--------+---------+
| abc    |     10 |       3 |
| xyz    |     20 |       4 |
+--------+--------+---------+
```

**users**

```
+----+---------+--------+
| id |  f_name | l_name |
+----+---------+--------+
|  1 |    abc  |    xyz |
|  2 |    abc  |    xyz |
|  3 |    abc  |    xyz |
|  4 |    abc  |    xyz |
|  5 |    abc  |    xyz |
|  6 |    abc  |    xyz |
+----+---------+--------+
```

**Expected output**

```
+--------+---------+---------+----------+---------+
| amount | result  | user_id | w_amount |  method |
+--------+---------+---------+----------+---------+
|     10 | success |       1 |          |         |
|     20 | failed  |       2 |          |         |
|        |         |       1 |       10 |         |
|        |         |       2 |       20 |         |
|        |         |       3 |          | abc     |
|        |         |       4 |          | xyz     |
+--------+---------+---------+----------+---------+
```

Please help Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of using INNER JOIN, you need to use LEFT/RIGHT OUTER JOIN. [You can start by reading this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join?rq=1)

Comment: To return exactly 10 records from those 3 tables then it seems you could use [UNION ALL](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp). But that's only usefull for output of the same type of fields.

Comment: Please provide sample data an desired results.

Comment: explaiing 10 records you want by saying wont do sample output is required!!

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i have already provided the example. user table has many users but only some of the users has topups, withdraws and transfer i have to find all those records from the all 3 tables which belongs to the user

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: @awsmsid . . . Your question is unclear.  There are multiple attempts to answer it, and you seem to reject all of them.  Without sample data, desired results, and a good explanation, there is no way to answer.  Strangers cannot read your mind.

Comment: i have provided the sample data please check now

Comment: Looks like a broken database to me. How can a withdraws record for user 10 exist, when there is no user with that ID? That doesn't seem to make sense and should be made impossible by applying an appropriate foreign key.

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. That includes clearly explaining how you get an answer no matter what the input is. Use enough steps, words, sentences & references to parts of examples.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner why a record for user 10 can't exist? what about if i created a withdraw record for user 10 and deleted that user from user table? one more scenerio can be here suppose withdraw is present without user_id. Please don't downvote for the question its a valid question i have the same scenerio thats why i posted this question

Comment: @ThorstenKettner for your kind of information i got the solution please check below LukStorms answer :)

Comment: @awsm sid: I didn't downvote. But in a properly designed database you couldn't delete a user when there is still data for that user. You also couldn't create withdraw data for a user that doesn't exist. There would be a foreign key on `withdraws.user_id` to `users.id`.

Answer (score 1):

Left joining them to the users and to a number works for this.

```
SELECT 
 tup.amount, tup.result, 
 usr.id as user_id, 
 wd.w_amount, 
 trans.method
FROM users usr
CROSS JOIN (SELECT generate_series n FROM generate_series(1, 3)) AS nr
LEFT JOIN topups tup ON tup.user_id = usr.id AND nr.n = 1
LEFT JOIN withdraws wd ON wd.user_id = usr.id AND nr.n = 2
LEFT JOIN transfers trans ON trans.user_id = usr.id AND nr.n = 3
WHERE (tup.user_id IS NOT NULL OR wd.user_id IS NOT NULL OR trans.user_id IS NOT NULL)
ORDER BY tup.user_id, wd.user_id, trans.user_id
```

Test it [here](https://rextester.com/WZLIT89379)

**Extra:**

A variation based on the comments [here](https://rextester.com/NVHS79498)

Comment: can i combine the value of two columns into one. suppose topups and withdraws belons to user id 1 and both have update_at so i want to combine the value of updated_at like CONCAT(tup.updated_at, ',', wd.updated_at) AS updated_at

Comment: but it its not concating the value each time i am getting a single value for updated_at like "2018-10-15 12:16:09.799762,,"  or  ",,2018-10-29 19:06:13.814336" i am trying to concat the updated_at of 3 tables

Comment: I would probably go for a `CONCAT_WS(',', tup.updated_at, wd.updated_at)`.  But you wanted the tables separated, so those 2 values are on different lines.

Comment: A `COALESCE(tup.updated_at, wd.updated_at, trans.updated_at)` would work in this setup, if you want only 1 "updated_at".

Comment: @awsmsid The problem with this is that each table has multiple records per user_id.  And to avoid a cartesian product join (and generate to many lines) you'd need to join on something extra.  Check out this [test](https://rextester.com/NVHS79498).  Basically, it joins on sub-queries that group on the user_id and the amount.  That's the closest I could get to what you tried to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `left join`s instead of `inner join`s:

```
SELECT * FROM users u
LEFT JOIN topups t
  ON u.id = t.user_id
LEFT JOIN withdraws w
  ON u.id = w.user_id
LEFT JOIN transfers tf
  ON u.id = tf.user_id
```

Comment: i tried but its not working. it returns all those records which do not belongs to users