# Is it always possible to avoid using a UNION in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have a super-simple table (called `useful_table`) with one column, like the below:

```
+----------+
| a_number |
+----------+
|     2    |
|     4    |
|     8    |
+----------+
```

And suppose I have a query with a `UNION`:

```
  SELECT
    a_number
  FROM
    useful_table
  WHERE
    a_number = 2
UNION
  SELECT
    a_number + 1
  FROM
    useful_table
  WHERE
    a_number = 2
;
```

I expect the result to be:

```
+----------+
| a_number |
+----------+
|     2    |
|     3    |
+----------+
```

Example query runs in Oracle, but should be applicable to other dialects.

Setup code here:

```
create table useful_table(a_number NUMBER);
insert into useful_table values (2);
insert into useful_table values (4);
insert into useful_table values (8);
```

*Is it possible to convert this query?*

*Is it always possible to convert `UNION`s to an alternative?*

Assumptions:

- I am using a subset of (Oracle) SQL, meaning:

  - I cannot use temporary tables.
  - I cannot use `UNION` or `UNION ALL`.
- Both sides of the `UNION` access data from the same table, but may change the raw data in different ways.

Comment: Yes, it is possible - for example with a cross join to a small table that can be created on the fly in the `FROM` clause, and a `CASE` expression in the `WHERE` clause. But before we go too far - do you really mean `UNION` and not `UNION ALL`? (You are aware that they both exist, and have different meaning, aren't you?) And then, **why** would you want to write the query without using `UNION` (or, more likely, `UNION ALL`)? What's the bigger picture here?

Comment: `If the SELECT clauses were the same (even if the WHERE clauses were different), then the query should be convertible using CASEs.` - This is not always true. There is only one row with the value of `a_number` = `2`. You can use `CASE` to alter the value is returned, but pulling both `2` and `3` requires an additional row with a value of `2`. This does not exist without a `UNION` or a `JOIN`, which `CASE` cannot produce. A more complete example might help us better understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: It's possible, by for example by left joining to a list of numbers. [Example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53795616/4003419). But if many fields need to be selected to get the same output as with unions, then it'll need also many coalesce's.

Comment: @mathguy I think this is applicable to `UNION` and `UNION ALL`, but I think that you're right; `UNION ALL` is more applicable here.

Comment: @PatrickTucci you're right, `CASE`s won't be able to make new rows (but can get the information in new columns). I've removed that line to hopefully reduce confusion.

Comment: @LukStorms I'm not sure that that would work for a more general case, when the fields may not all be numbers? If you've got an answer though, it would be great to have it fleshed out!

Comment: @AJarofClay Have a look at the example in my previous comment. You'll notice that the numbers are just used in the JOIN.  Putting the joined tables/sub-queries next to each other on separated rows if it would select f.e. `table1.*, subquery1.*, table2.*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always possible to rewrite a `UNION` as a `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

So

```
  SELECT
    <expression1>
  FROM
    useful_table
  WHERE
    <predicate1>
UNION
  SELECT
   <expression2>
  FROM
    useful_table
  WHERE
    <predicate2>
;
```

would become

```
SELECT DISTINCT COALESCE(u1.<expression1> , u2.<expression2> )
FROM            useful_table u1
FULL OUTER JOIN useful_table u2
ON              1 = 0
WHERE           u1.<predicate1>
                OR u2.<predicate2>
```

Or in your specific example

```
SELECT DISTINCT COALESCE(u1.a_number, u2.a_number + 1)
FROM   useful_table u1
       FULL OUTER JOIN useful_table u2
                    ON 1 = 0
WHERE  u1.a_number = 2
        OR u2.a_number = 2
```

Comment: It is not always possible.  What if you want both rows and there is overlapping criteria, to me that means you want a Union.

Comment: @JoeC - The combined `FULL OUTER JOIN` and `DISTINCT` will return the same results. Please provide a specific example where you think they don't return the same thing. The `FULL OUTER JOIN` on false condition basically provides a `UNION ALL` ed result set but with the columns not merged (done by `COALESCE`).

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to duplicate output rows using a `CROSS JOIN` with a `CONNECT BY` cte.

In general however this works under the assumptions that :

- only one table is involved
- there is a single `WHERE` clause
- the operations to perform on duplicated records are simple enough to be implemented based on an incrementing integer, as returned by the `CONNECT BY` cte (which still leaves quite some room to act)

The following query does match your exact use case :

```
with data as (select level -1 l from dual connect by level <= 2)
select a_number + l
from useful_table, data
where a_number = 2
```

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate whether you think this will extend to the general case?

Comment: @JarOfClay : done ; but your question is quite wide so it is uneasy to provide a very accurate answer...

Answer (score -3):

I will use Union when nothing else will do.  I have always found that joins and case constructs from one query always perform better than a Union.

However as someone commented, there is a time when a row can match two cases criteria and it cant happen with case logic.

Queries are specific to the goal, but I think it is fair to say that you can not always replace Union.

In your specific use case, it can.